# HTML form to PHP mail script not getting $post data

Tags: php, html, email

I'm having some trouble with a basic mail PHP script. I can get the email to send, but can't get the variables from the html form.

Here is the code, any ideas?

```
<form action='sendmail.php' method="POST">

    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />

    <label for="email">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number" />

    <label for="comments">Message</label>
    <textarea id="comments" name="message"></textarea>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the PHP file

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["number"];
$message = $_POST["message"];


$to      = 'sam.weinhandl@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form Message';
$message = "Name: ". $name  . "\r\nPhone: " . $phone . "\r\nMessage: " . $message;
$headers = "From: " . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: `method="POST"` and `$_GET["name"]`? Might want to review that again.

Comment: You are using the "POST" method and using superglobals $_GET to get the post data that's wrong. if you want to get the post data use superglobals $_POST or otherwise use $_REQUEST to get the value.

Answer (score 3):

You are using POST method to send form data to PHP. Use `$_POST` to get the values.

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["number"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

Comment: Sorry I was experimenting before I copied and pasted.

I have used, $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST and all I am getting in the email is:

Answer (score 0):

Either change method when posting your form

```
<form action='sendmail.php' method="GET">
```

**Or**

change the variables

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email_from = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["number"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_POST or $_REQUEST to fetch values. $_REQUEST will be the  best option because it works for both get and post methods.

```
$name = $_REQUEST["name"];
$email_from = $_REQUEST["email"];
$phone = $_REQUEST["number"];
$message = $_REQUEST["message"];
```

Answer (score 0):

U should change your method to 'GET'.
Or u should change the variables.
The answers above all work.